# Can't Post on second formLogin()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**When I try to login in the second formLogin() i get 'POST' not supported but not in the first.**

this is my code
can you merge the two or is any other way to do it?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService trainerAppUserService;
    private final AppUserService vereinAppUserService;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(
            @Qualifier("trainer") AppUserService trainerAppUserService,
            @Qualifier("verein") AppUserService vereinAppUserService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.trainerAppUserService = trainerAppUserService;
        this.vereinAppUserService = vereinAppUserService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(vereinDaoAuthenticationProvider());


        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/Verein/**/*.*").authenticated() // Zugriff auf /Verein/Homepage nur für authentifizierte Benutzer erlauben
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage("/Verein/LogIn")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/Verein/LogIn")
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/Verein/Homepage"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/Verein/LogOut")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/Verein/LogIn")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean

    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(trainerDaoAuthenticationProvider());


        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/Trainer/**/*.*").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage("/Trainer/LogIn")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/Trainer/LogIn")
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/Trainer/Homepage"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/Trainer/LogOut")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/Trainer/LogIn")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }



    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider trainerDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(trainerAppUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider vereinDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(vereinAppUserService);
        return provider;
    }

}
```

I tried making different Orders and Seperating in different Classes, don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Do you have both of these `FilterChain` beans defined simultaneously?  That certainly won't work, and to be honest, I'm surprised Spring didn't toss an exception.  What I believe you're trying to accomplish is different behavior for a user based on their login, this is usually controlled through roles and privileges.

Comment: Ah should i define different Roles for each User-Group ?

Comment: yeah, have a single login page and define roles for your users that control what actions the users can take once they've logged in.